# On ubuntu how to create a directory path in one statement

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On ubuntu is there a way to create a directory path in one statement?

Lets say I have the dir `/tmp/foo` with no subdirectories, and I want to create `/tmp/foo/bar/baz`.

`mkdir /tmp/foo/bar/baz` fails with `mkdir: cannot create directory /tmp/foo/bar/baz: No such file or directory`

Is there a statement that can do this trick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/baz
```

From 'man mkdir':

```
-p, --parents
      no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Comment: Auww, your right. Overlooked that one.